# Sort multidimensional array by existence of key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have array:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [var_for_type] => inside
        [show_about] => on
        [pagethumb] => on
        [postthumb] => on
        [portfoliothumb] => on
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [var_for_type] => shadow
        [show_about] => on
        [box_for_type] => Array ( [0] => cvb [1] => odf [2] => o-koshkah )
        [postthumb] => on
    )
)
```

And I need to sort it by existence of key 'box_for_type'. If key 'box_for_type' exists, than output it before other arrays in multidimensional array. How can I do it?

Comment: With a [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) using a callback that checks whether `box_for_type` is set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [usort()](http://php.net/usort) function where you can define your own function for comparing elements:

```
 $sample = [
   ['test' => 'a'],
   ['test' => 'g', 'box_for_type' => []],   
   ['test' => 'b'],
   ['test' => 'c', 'box_for_type' => []],
 ];


usort($sample, function ($a, $b){
   return (int)!array_key_exists('box_for_type', $a); 
});

print_r($sample);
```